# Is there a way to find Instagram webview bottom navigation bar is visible or not in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, instagram

As seen in the screen shot, Instagram hides/shows the bottom navigation bar when we scroll up or down in the webview(browser (iOS Safari v15.3))

Is there a JavaScript technique to determine whether the IG Bottombar is visible or not?

All I know is that the IG webview was used to load that page using 
`userAgent.includes("Instagram")`

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Update: Here's the sample screen [recording gif](https://gifyu.com/image/SbeLZ) example

Comment: Which browser are you using? It's not showing up for me at the bottom. The solution would be to find if the  bar has a specific ID. Then from there we would be able to, with javascript, find if it exists on the DOM. We could also check if it exists and the css property 'display' is set to none.

Comment: Hey @Raffael, Sorry, It's iOS safari v15.3, Updated the question

Comment: I'm facing the same issue but didn't find a solution yet